# [C cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java

I'm trying to print fields of java.lang.Integer class. Only the primitive fields, and arrays, its elements - the indexes.

I'm getting error at the array printing part.

this is snippet code I have for that:

```
else if(field.getType().isArray()) 
{                   
   String printValue = Arrays.toString((Object[]) field.get(obj));                  
}
```

However it gives me the error mentioned in the title.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Can you provide a short and complete example which reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This field's type is `char[]`. You can't cast that to `Object[]` because primitive arrays aren't instances of `Object[]`.

You may find the [`Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) class's accessor methods useful.

For example:

```
Object val = field.get(obj);
Object[] objs =
    IntStream.range(0, Array.getLength(val))
        .mapToObj(i -> Array.get(val, i))
        .toArray();
String printValue = Arrays.toString(objs);
```

Although note this does create at least an array and box all of the values. You don't need to create these if you just have an if/else ladder testing the type of the array, and explicitly casting:

```
if (val instanceof char[]) {
  printValue = Arrays.toString((char[]) val);
} else if (val instanceof int[]) {
  printValue = Arrays.toString((int[]) val);
} // Etc.
```